# Ionic - What is the best way to notify pages that a variable has been changed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Let's say we have a page `ListItemPage` showing the list of items:

- In the ts file, we have a variable `items: any = [];`
- In the html file, we have `<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">`

The user can click a (+) button to push another page `AddItemPage` on which he will create a new item. When save is clicked, the new item is saved in the database (by a service) and the page is popped.

What's the best/usual way to notify the `ListItemPage` that its `items` variable should be updated?

- Should I use Events? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/
- Should I use Observable?
- Something else?

Comment: you can use either of them.. its your preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the best/usual way to notify the ListItemPage that its items
>   variable should be updated?
>
> - Should I use Events? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/
> - Should I use Observable?

Well if you already have a service *related to the items* (maybe a service that gets the items from the backend), it'd be better to use Observables in order to keep everything consistent.

```
@Injectable()
export class YourItemsService {

    public onItemsChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    // ...

    public changeItems(someParam: any): void {
        // ...

        // Send the new data to the subscribers
        this.onItemsChange.next(newItems);
    }

}
```

That way each page can subscribe to it and be updated when the data changes, and can use the same service to change the data, knowing that the change will also be propagated to all the pages that are subscribed to it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'another-page',
    templateUrl: 'another-page.html'
})
export class AnotherPagePage {

    constructor(private yourItemsService: YourItemsService) {}

    updateItems(data: any) { 
        // Use the service to modify the data, keeping everyone updated
        this.yourItemsService.changeItems(data);
    }

}
```

And...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-page',
    templateUrl: 'some-page.html'
})
export class SomePagePage {

    private itemsChangeSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private yourItemsService: YourItemsService) {
        // Subscribe to changes in the items
        this.itemsChangeSubscription = this.yourItemsService.onItemsChange.subscribe(data => {
            // Update the data of the page...
            // ...
        });
    }

    ionViewWillUnload() {
        // Clear the itemsChangeSubscription
        this.itemsChangeSubscription && this.itemsChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Why doing this? If you need to execute some logic every time the items are modified (like updating a total amount in another service, or any other property) you can do that in the service, keeping that logic centralized in a single place. **So each page should worry about how to handle the new data to update its current state, but any other change will be handled by the service**

---

If for some reason you don't want to use observables (you don't have a centralized service, and creating a new one only for a single event doesn't sound like a good idea), you could just use **[Ionic's Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)**.

If you do this and need to execute some custom logic every time the event is published, you'd need to repeat that code on every page that subscribes to each event.

**Additional details about the Ionic's events**

If you take a look at the implementation of Ionic's Events (**[source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/util/events.ts)**) you'd see that internally Ionic does not use Observables but an array where the callbacks are stored in order to be executed when the event is published

Answer (score 1):

Uf a tough one. This seems like a "It depends" kinda question so without detailed description of your needs I am afraid it is impossible to answer what is best.

So here is **another way** to update `items`.

Implement the `ionViewWillEnter()` method with the data fetching logic ([more about navigating-lifecycle-events](http://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/)).

This method will fire every time a page is about to be shown e.g. when it is about to become active. So by implementing it something like this:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.dataService.getItems()
        .then(result => {
            this.items = result;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

And in your `dataService`:

```
let _items = [];

public getItems() {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => { 
        if(!this._items || this._items.lenght == 0) {
            // this._items = Read items from DB / web service ...
        }

        resolve(this._items);
    });
}

public addItem(item: any) {
    this._items.push(item);
    // update db..
}
```

the page will have fresh data every time it gets displayed.

When you update the data by calling the `addItem` method you make sure all following calls to the `getItems` method get fresh data. You can also say that the data is cached so there are no unnecessary DB querying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem here is that we **always** update `items`. Even if nothing was modified on the other page. I'm just wondering what is the usual/standard way to do this...

Comment: Well there is no way around reading the data every time the page is displayed. With this approach your `items` are stored in the `dataService` instead of your `ListItemPage`. Anyway this is just another way for you to choose from.